# If statement with scrolltop does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an animation happen once the webpage is at a certain part of the page. I have looked at other people queries and my problem is similar but it does not work.

here is the code:

```
if($('html,body').scrollTop() > 400) {
   $('.fish_one').animate({"margin-left":"+=65%"},1000);
    $('.fish_two').animate({"margin-left":"-=10%"},1000);
    $('.left').animate({"opacity":"+=1"},1000); 
    $('header').css({"background-color":"#fff"});
    $('header a').css({"color":"#94d9f8"});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the if statement every time the page scrolls, not just on load. Use $(window).scroll(function(){

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        alert("lower");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6f1hat8/1/)

EDIT: to prevent the function from repeating itself:

```
var pos = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(($(window).scrollTop() > 400) !== pos ){
        alert("changed");
    }
    pos = $(window).scrollTop() > 400;
 });
```

OR

```
var pos = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(($(window).scrollTop() > 400) && !pos ){
        alert("just passed breakpoint");
    }
    pos = $(window).scrollTop() > 400;
 });
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6f1hat8/2/)

Comment: that does work the event listener but the function repeats itself for example it will do the margin part none stop.

Comment: It still does not work. it redirects me back to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to an event listener like this:

```
var eventTriggered=false;
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 400 && !eventTriggered) {
        alert("success");
        eventTriggered=true;
    }else if($(document).scrollTop() < 400){
        eventTriggered=false;
    }     
});
```

This one works